# Need help getting a web font to work in a template

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts

I have a template for Wordpress that I downloaded an it comes with what I consider a hard-to-read (because it is so skinny) font for h1 and h2 text.  It is called Century Gothic.  I have a font on my Mac that I'd rather use called Noteworthy.  I have used an online conversion to convert it from OTF to several web-font styles (eot, svg, ttf, woff).  The conversion outfit also provided a bit of code.

The problem is can't find where the Century-Gothic is defined so I can replace it with Noteworthy.  I've found all the instances where it is part of

Here is the code I've inserted in the file style.css.

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
    font-family: Noteworthy;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Noteworthy';
    src: url('fonts/Noteworthy.eot');
    src: url('fonts/Noteworthy.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/Noteworthy.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/Noteworthy.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #750000;
}
```

And here is an example of its use in various style definitions:

```
.post div h2 {
    margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: Century-Gothic, Helvetica, Arial;
    color: #750000;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

I've gone through and replaced all instances of this with Noteworthy yet when I refresh my page, the old font remains.

There is a folder at the top level of this template folder called Fonts where the Noteworthy font files reside.

Please note that I'm a rank novice at this and have been trying to learn as I go by checking online resources but this one really stumps me.

My site's URL is http://scruffydog.org and you can see some of what I'm talking about.  The script at the top (Stories...) is in Noteworthy but it is a PNG.  The headers in each of the posts ("Hello World," "Note Post," etc.) are primarily what I'm trying to fix.

I'm on a Mac Mini running OS X 10.11.5, using Safari.

A secondary question has to do with the post that is third from the left whose title is a URL.  I have no idea how to alter that one at all!

Any tips or resources would be greatly appreciated.  I can also zip the css file and email it if that would help.  There is no hurry on this as it's just an old retired man's hobby.

Thank you!

-Tod

Comment: have you replaced this line `font-family: Century-Gothic, Helvetica, Arial;` with `Noteworthy`?

Answer (score 1):

If you view full source on this page you will not see this code. In Chrome press Command + Shift + i and search for hello and you'll see what I inserted below.

Your theme is using Cufon. This is a javascript font replacement script.

You can comment out:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://scruffydog.org/wp-content/themes/DailyNotes/js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
```

or disable the font replacement for the h* tags.

```
<h2><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Hello " style="width: 49px;     
height: 18px;"><canvas width="64" height="19" style="width: 64px; 
height: 19px; top: -1px; left: -1px;"></canvas><cufontext>Hello   
</cufontext></cufon><cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="world!" 
style="width: 49px; height: 18px;"><canvas width="67" height="19" 
style="width: 67px; height: 19px; top: -1px; left: -1px;"></canvas>
<cufontext>world!</cufontext></cufon></h2>
```

If you are using more fonts utilizing it could cause issues.

Comment: @ David:  thank you for analyzing this and providing a good solution.  I found the line you referenced first in the header.php file and simply deleted it.  Refreshed my page and things are indeed looking good. Your help on a Sunday afternoon is indeed appreciated.

Comment: @Pandora no problem. Glad I could help.